# DataTables warning: table id=users-table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Tags: html, jquery, datatables

I am trying to retrieve data in the database with DataTables in laravel but I getting two error: DataTables warning: table id=users-table - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

my table looks like this:

```
<section id="basic-datatable">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="card">
         <table class="datatables-basic table" id="users-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
              <th>id</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal to add new record -->
  <div class="modal modal-slide-in fade" id="modals-slide-in">
    <div class="modal-dialog sidebar-sm">
      <form class="add-new-record modal-content pt-0">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">×</button>
        <div class="modal-header mb-1">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Record</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body flex-grow-1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label" for="basic-icon-default-fullname">Full Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control dt-full-name"
              id="basic-icon-default-fullname"
              placeholder="John Doe"
              aria-label="John Doe"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label" for="basic-icon-default-post">Post</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="basic-icon-default-post"
              class="form-control dt-post"
              placeholder="Web Developer"
              aria-label="Web Developer"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label" for="basic-icon-default-email">Email</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="basic-icon-default-email"
              class="form-control dt-email"
              placeholder="john.doe@example.com"
              aria-label="john.doe@example.com"
            />
            <small class="form-text text-muted"> You can use letters, numbers & periods </small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label" for="basic-icon-default-date">Joining Date</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              class="form-control dt-date"
              id="basic-icon-default-date"
              placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
              aria-label="MM/DD/YYYY"
            />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group mb-4">
            <label class="form-label" for="basic-icon-default-salary">Salary</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="basic-icon-default-salary"
              class="form-control dt-salary"
              placeholder="$12000"
              aria-label="$12000"
            />
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary data-submit mr-1">Submit</button>
          <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

my java script is:

```
     * DataTables Basic
     */
        $(function () {
        'use strict';
            var dt_basic_table = $('.datatables-basic'),
      if (dt_basic_table.length) {
        var dt_basic = dt_basic_table.DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            autoWidth: false,
            ajax: '{!! route('users.data') !!}',
                language: {
                    url: '{{ asset('lang/' . (in_array(\Lang::locale(), ['dk', 'en']) ? \Lang::locale() : 'en') . '/datatable.json') }}'
                },
                drawCallback: function(){
                    var length_select = $(".dataTables_length");
                    var select = $(".dataTables_length").find("select");
                    select.addClass("tablet__select");
                },
          columns: [
            { data: 'responsive_id' },
            { data: 'id' },
            { data: 'id' }, // used for sorting so will hide this column
            { data: 'full_name' },
            { data: 'email' },
            { data: 'start_date' },
            { data: 'salary' },
            { data: '' },
            { data: '' }
          ],
          columnDefs: [
            {
              // For Responsive
              className: 'control',
              orderable: false,
              responsivePriority: 2,
              targets: 0
            },
            {
              // For Checkboxes
              targets: 1,
              orderable: false,
              responsivePriority: 3,
              render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return (
                  '<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input class="custom-control-input dt-checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkbox' +
                  data +
                  '" /><label class="custom-control-label" for="checkbox' +
                  data +
                  '"></label></div>'
                );
              },
              checkboxes: {
                selectAllRender:
                  '<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="checkboxSelectAll" /><label class="custom-control-label" for="checkboxSelectAll"></label></div>'
              }
            },
            {
              targets: 2,
              visible: false
            },
            {
              responsivePriority: 1,
              targets: 4
            },
            {
              // Label
              targets: -2,
              render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                var $status_number = full['status'];
                var $status = {
                  1: { title: 'Current', class: 'badge-light-primary' },
                  2: { title: 'Professional', class: ' badge-light-success' },
                  3: { title: 'Rejected', class: ' badge-light-danger' },
                  4: { title: 'Resigned', class: ' badge-light-warning' },
                  5: { title: 'Applied', class: ' badge-light-info' }
                };
                if (typeof $status[$status_number] === 'undefined') {
                  return data;
                }
                return (
                  '<span class="badge badge-pill ' +
                  $status[$status_number].class +
                  '">' +
                  $status[$status_number].title +
                  '</span>'
                );
              }
            },
            {
              // Actions
              targets: -1,
              title: 'Actions',
              orderable: false,
              render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return (
                  '<div class="d-inline-flex">' +
                  '<a class="pr-1 dropdown-toggle hide-arrow text-primary" data-toggle="dropdown">' +
                  feather.icons['more-vertical'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4' }) +
                  '</a>' +
                  '<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">' +
                  '<a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-item">' +
                  feather.icons['file-text'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4 mr-50' }) +
                  'Details</a>' +
                  '<a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-item">' +
                  feather.icons['archive'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4 mr-50' }) +
                  'Archive</a>' +
                  '<a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-item delete-record">' +
                  feather.icons['trash-2'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4 mr-50' }) +
                  'Delete</a>' +
                  '</div>' +
                  '</div>' +
                  '<a href="javascript:;" class="item-edit">' +
                  feather.icons['edit'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4' }) +
                  '</a>'
                );
              }
            }
          ],
          order: [[2, 'desc']],
          dom:
            '<"card-header border-bottom p-1"<"head-label"><"dt-action-buttons text-right"B>><"d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mx-0 row"<"col-sm-12 col-md-6"l><"col-sm-12 col-md-6"f>>t<"d-flex justify-content-between mx-0 row"<"col-sm-12 col-md-6"i><"col-sm-12 col-md-6"p>>',
          displayLength: 7,
          lengthMenu: [7, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
          buttons: [
            {
              extend: 'collection',
              className: 'btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle mr-2',
              text: feather.icons['share'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4 mr-50' }) + 'Export',
              buttons: [
                {
                  extend: 'print',
                  text: feather.icons['printer'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4 mr-50' }) + 'Print',
                  className: 'dropdown-item',
                  exportOptions: { columns: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7] }
                },
                {
                  extend: 'csv',
                  text: feather.icons['file-text'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4 mr-50' }) + 'Csv',
                  className: 'dropdown-item',
                  exportOptions: { columns: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7] }
                },
                {
                  extend: 'excel',
                  text: feather.icons['file'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4 mr-50' }) + 'Excel',
                  className: 'dropdown-item',
                  exportOptions: { columns: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7] }
                },
                {
                  extend: 'pdf',
                  text: feather.icons['clipboard'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4 mr-50' }) + 'Pdf',
                  className: 'dropdown-item',
                  exportOptions: { columns: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7] }
                },
                {
                  extend: 'copy',
                  text: feather.icons['copy'].toSvg({ class: 'font-small-4 mr-50' }) + 'Copy',
                  className: 'dropdown-item',
                  exportOptions: { columns: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7] }
                }
              ],
              init: function (api, node, config) {
                $(node).removeClass('btn-secondary');
                $(node).parent().removeClass('btn-group');
                setTimeout(function () {
                  $(node).closest('.dt-buttons').removeClass('btn-group').addClass('d-inline-flex');
                }, 50);
              }
            },
            {
              text: feather.icons['plus'].toSvg({ class: 'mr-50 font-small-4' }) + 'Add New Record',
              className: 'create-new btn btn-primary',
              attr: {
                'data-toggle': 'modal',
                'data-target': '#modals-slide-in'
              },
              init: function (api, node, config) {
                $(node).removeClass('btn-secondary');
              }
            }
          ],
          responsive: {
            details: {
              display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal({
                header: function (row) {
                  var data = row.data();
                  return 'Details of ' + data['full_name'];
                }
              }),
              type: 'column',
              renderer: function (api, rowIdx, columns) {
                var data = $.map(columns, function (col, i) {
                  return col.title !== '' // ? Do not show row in modal popup if title is blank (for check box)
                    ? '<tr data-dt-row="' +
                        col.rowIndex +
                        '" data-dt-column="' +
                        col.columnIndex +
                        '">' +
                        '<td>' +
                        col.title +
                        ':' +
                        '</td> ' +
                        '<td>' +
                        col.data +
                        '</td>' +
                        '</tr>'
                    : '';
                }).join('');
    
                return data ? $('<table class="table"/>').append(data) : false;
              }
            }
          },
          language: {
            paginate: {
              // remove previous & next text from pagination
              previous: '&nbsp;',
              next: '&nbsp;'
            }
          }
        });
     //   $('div.head-label').html('<h6 class="mb-0">DataTable with Buttons</h6>');
      }
    
      // Flat Date picker
      if (dt_date_table.length) {
        dt_date_table.flatpickr({
          monthSelectorType: 'static',
          dateFormat: 'm/d/Y'
        });
      }
    
      // Add New record
      // ? Remove/Update this code as per your requirements ?
    
      $('.data-submit').on('click', function () {
        var $new_name = $('.add-new-record .dt-full-name').val(),
          $new_post = $('.add-new-record .dt-post').val(),
          $new_email = $('.add-new-record .dt-email').val(),
          $new_date = $('.add-new-record .dt-date').val(),
          $new_salary = $('.add-new-record .dt-salary').val();
    
        if ($new_name != '') {
          dt_basic.row
            .add({
              responsive_id: null,
              id: count,
              full_name: $new_name,
              post: $new_post,
              email: $new_email,
              start_date: $new_date,
              salary: '$' + $new_salary,
              status: 5
            })
            .draw();
          count++;
          $('.modal').modal('hide');
        }
      });
    
      // Delete Record
      $('.datatables-basic tbody').on('click', '.delete-record', function () {
        dt_basic.row($(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();`enter code here`
      });
    });
```

How can solve these errors with scripts?

Comment: The link in your question (http://datatables.net/tn/7) gives you all infos about how to diagnose and solve the error. It's impossible to say anything else, as we don't see the data you get from your AJAX request (and you didn't provide them),

Comment: It keeps loading and when i click in the table it shows **No data available in table**